# Glade / GtkScrolledWindow hides Child

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk3, glade

I have some Problems with Glade and GTK3+, i made an Dialog-Box, added a GtkNotebook in it, made a new Page (Tab) and added a "GtkScrolledWindow" in it, in that ScrolledWindow a placed a Box with several Spin-Buttons and Labels. In the Editor itself shows them exactly as i want it (you see in the picture below). But in the Preview of Glade or by running with Python, the Child of the "GtkScrolledWindow" wont show up. Why is that? GTK dont export any errors.

[image: Preview wont show ScrolledWindows Child]
Please Help!

**EDIT: (4.7.16):**

I detected the reason why:
Glade don't place the Child of the "GtKScrolledWindow" in its .glade File. I wondered after opening up the .glade File after saving, but without the Content of the GtkScrolledWindow. Main Bug in Glade?

[image]

**EDIT: (8.7.16):**

It really is a bug, build the dialog_window new from scratch, and copied the boxes in it. Had to tweak around a bit, not that fancy to handle the graphical interface, but now it works flawlessly

Comment: What do you mean, the child of the `GtkScrolledWindow`?

Comment: Yes,  it won't show up

Comment: I see what you mean. The background image is in Glade, and the foreground image is your program. The problem with `GtkScrolledWindow`s is that they try to be as small as possible. Try `set_size_request` on the `GtkScrolledWindow`.

Comment: Correct (should have explained that :-) ,  I tried to set size requests,  but no difference in the preview :-(

Comment: What kind of a box are you using?

Comment: Vbox with 6 rows, in every second row is another 2x3 grid, tried a 1 row Vbox as parent and after that a scrolled window of that whole cascade. No result,  without scrolled window,  everything works fine..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116323/discussion-between-oldtechaa-and-benny-h).

Comment: Instead of editing your question, it is recommended to self-answer. This uses SO's method of showing a problem is solved.